# Why does this code add a list item only once?

Tags: android, listview

I'm making a button to add a list item each time I click it. I have this code but it only adds a list item the first time. How can I make it so that it adds one each time I click the button. Or maybe even a specific range of times?

Declaration of variables in the class.

```
//LIST OF ARRAY STRINGS WHICH WILL SERVE AS LIST ITEMS
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

//DEFINING A STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE THE DATA OF THE LISTVIEW
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterForPic;

//RECORDING HOW MANY TIMES THE BUTTON HAS BEEN CLICKED
int clickCounter=0;
private ListView mListView;
```

Initialisation inside the onCreate().

```
if (mListView == null) {
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.photosListView);
    }

    adapterForPic=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapterForPic);
```

The methods to do the inserting.

```
//METHOD WHICH WILL HANDLE DYNAMIC INSERTION
public void addItems(View v) {
    listItems.add("Clicked : "+clickCounter);
    adapterForPic.notifyDataSetChanged();
    clickCounter++;
}

protected ListView getListView() {
    if (mListView == null) {
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.photosListView);
    }
    return mListView;
}

protected void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
}

protected ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
    ListAdapter adapter = getListView().getAdapter();
    if (adapter instanceof HeaderViewListAdapter) {
        return ((HeaderViewListAdapter)adapter).getWrappedAdapter();
    } else {
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a simple activity with a `ListView` and a `Button`, and copied your code into it. I deleted `getListAdapter()` because it's never called within the code you posted. My app correctly continues to add views every time I click the button, which makes me think the problem is in code you *didn't* post; can you post everything from your activity/layout instead of just pieces?

Comment: [This](https://codeshare.io/adkV0B) is my full Java code in the Post.java file. [Here](https://codeshare.io/al41Pm) is my Layout file.

Comment: This suggestion is based on some weird behavior I have seen in the past. Try changing "listItems.add("Clicked : "+clickCounter);" to "listItems.add("Clicked : " + String.valueOf(clickCounter));"

Comment: @Hahn I tried that and nothing changes, what would you suggest me to do? Since I need to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: For testing, try setting your listview's height to match_parent. Just to see if anything happens when you click.

Comment: @Hahn Tried setting it to a large value like 300dp and it worked. But how would one proceed to make this process from the code?

Comment: Without trying out the code and layout, I'd say you can put it inside a LinearLayout. However, I would suggest that you review the fact that you are trying to put a Listview (already a scrollableView) inside a scrollableView. You may run into headaches regarding this later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in the height of the ListView Element. It was `wrap_content` and therefore only showed me one List Item.